# How can I model my data in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I'm looking at whether Drupal 7 might be a good choice for a site I need to do in my spare time on a voluntary basis i.e. I don't have time to build it from scratch using one of the PHP frameworks which is what I would typically do.

The site will be built around animal data. I will have Animals, Pictures, Locations and Votes (votes against pictures of the animals). I also need to store meta data about the images like animal orientation, location etc.

My question is how do I achieve these data relationships in Drupal 7? Do I need content-types, Views, Taxonomies, Vocabularies or a combination of all of these things? Or do I need to write a custom module with its own data structure?

I want to use Drupal 7 as I think by the time I complete the project, Drupal 7 will be released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you still need to know the answer to this - but I'd say that Drupal would be pretty good for what you want to do.

You are likely to need CCK types & views. Taxonomies might be needed as well, depending a bit on what you want to do with the data.

Try to create a basic drupal 7 site, and create some CCK types. Then you can take a look at how hard it is to build things up. There's loads of good videos which can teach you about this.

James

Comment: Thanks. I decided to build it with Symfony but this is good to know.